# Alerta erronea al momento en que se ejecuta el ajax y regresa mensaje

Tags: ajax, sweetalert, mensajes

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo un modal, donde se tiene este script para realizar una solicitud Ajax que recibe los parámetros de varios archivos que deberán subirse al servidor.

```js
script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button#cargarArchivoMultiple").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let form = e.target.closest('form');
            let formData = new FormData(form);
            console.log(...formData);

            $.ajax({
                url: "procesarArchivos.php",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(){
                    $("#modalCargarProyectoResguardoMultiple").modal('hide');
                    swal("Se Cargaron los  Archivos Exitosamente!","Aceptar","success");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#modalCargarProyectoResguardoMultiple").modal('hide');
                    swal("No se pudieron Cargar los Archivos","Aceptar","error");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                },
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Se procesa la petición correctamente, ya que si guarda los archivos previamente seleccionados, pero en lugar de enviar la alerta swal que indica que "se cargaron los archivos exitosamente", envía el swal donde indica que "no se pudieron cargar los archivos"...

Es algo raro por que solo me esta pasando esta situación con el procesamiento de archivos.

Saludos y buen día!!.

Comment: Y sabes qué está devolviendo el PHP? Porque puede estar cumpliendo su cometido, pero lo que haga tu llamado ajax depende de lo que devuelva

Comment: Creo que seria conveniente revisar ese detalle.  Gracias @Alfabravo